# NGINX Reverse Proxy microservices built with cherrypy

Tags: python-3.x, cherrypy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm building a smart greenhouse for a university project and we must follow a **microservices architecture** and use **cherrypy**. My proposed solution is having different microservices handling the different telemetrics using nginx, docker and docker-compose.

I'm using nginx for reverse proxy my front-end and all the microservices, but how do I handle the uri? Can nginx handle URIs with `<ids>`?

Cherrypy doesn't seen to provide horizontal scalling, the [RESTful-style dispatcher](https://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/advanced.html#restful) provided seems like just provides monolithic approach.

My current NGINX:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:80;
    }
    location /api/v1/moisture {
        proxy_pass http://moisture:5001;
    }
    location /api/v1/light {
        proxy_pass http://moisture:5001;
    }
}
```

My API should look something like this `/api/v1/greenhouse/<id>/moisture`, were `moisture` can be every telemetric I can measure like `humidity` or `light`.

The objective was that nginx could send a request to `/api/v1/greenhouse/<id>/moisture` to the moisture service and a request to `/api/v1/greenhouse/<id>/humidity` the humidity service, since cherrypy does not provide a solution.